# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection, sqlcmd

i have this error:

Password: HResult 0xFFFFFFFF, Level 16, State 1
SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible.
 Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

I try to connect by cmd to sql server and i use this command:

sqlcmd -U sa -S server\istance_name

The prompt requires the password, but when i Insert the password, i receive the error message.

I see the Sql server configuration manager and the TCP/IP in Enabled.

I try a telnet connection on port 1443 and it is ok.

Have someone solution?

Comment: I assume "1443" is a typo for "1433"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic powers are telling me that the SQL Server Browser service is disabled or firewalled on your server. Without that, servers with instance names cannot be resolved.

Comment: Where do I start the sql server Browser? in my local pc or in the sql server pc? Is this change need a restart of sql server?

Comment: You start it on the machine where SQL Server is running. It does not require restarting either the machine or SQL Server itself.